# LD can't find libraries when building with cmake

Tags: linux, cmake, ld, ubuntu-21.04

For my thesis work I will have to work with a project that was created with cmake. Therefore, I installed cmake on my PopOS! 21.04 laptop.

```
cmake --version
cmake version 3.21.3
```

dpkg doesn't find it though (I had build cmake myself, can I add it to dpkg somehow).

```
    dpkg -l cmake
    ||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
    +++-==============-============-============- 
   ===============================>
    un  cmake          <none>       <none>       (no description 
    available)`
```

So I went ahead and downloaded the source code and extracted it on my Desktop. Inside the root source folder I entered:

```
mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
sudo cmake --build . --config Release --target install
```

which works until I get this:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXrandr /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig /usr/bin/ld: cannot find
> -lXrandr /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXinerama /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfontconfig collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status gmake[2]: *** [EnvironmentSimulator/Libraries/esminiLib/CMakeFiles/esminiLib.dir/build.make:122:
> EnvironmentSimulator/Libraries/esminiLib/libesminiLib.so] Error 1
> gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:584:
> EnvironmentSimulator/Libraries/esminiLib/CMakeFiles/esminiLib.dir/all]
> Error 2 gmake: *** [Makefile:136: all] Error 2

For me it looks like ld cannot find the libraries, if I look if xrandr is in /usr/bin/ it is. I tried linking it with a LD_PATH sth which didnt work and writing to the ld config file.

So now I don't know what else I can try.

Comment: `cannot find -lXrandr` means your linker could not find a file called `libXrandr.so`. Use packages.ubuntu.com to figure out which package contains that file (libxrandr.so) and install it.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I installed all libs and noticed this:

"Note, selecting 'libfontconfig1' instead of 'libfontconfig' "

Now when I build the other libs are found, this one isn*t

Comment: You always need the "*-dev" packages to link with.

Comment: Thank you very much ! It runs now :)